# JAVA Sorting 4 Strings in Lexicographical Order

Tags: java

im a beginner Java programmer! 
Im working on a problem set. That takes 4 Strings and sorts them by Lexicographical order. I initially used

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

strings.add(first);
strings.add(second);
strings.add(third);

Collections.sort(strings);
```

This worked however my instructor was adamant on using conditionals. :( 
I've spent the last 2 hours attempting to use the compareTo() method. My code is compiling, however there seems to be a logic error. I was hoping someone could point it out and give me an explanation of why.

Also, I'm new here. I tried really hard to make my code easy to read. If there are any tips send them my way! Also if there are any rules or something im not doing right please let me know also. Thanks.

EDIT: Ive been trying and trying to paste this code. Stack is just not letting it happen.

Here is my Gist: https://gist.github.com/mattmccarthy11/b8b5315493fe43efb42c

Comment: You really made it overcomplicated.

Comment: Why don't you take an array and compare the positions ?

Comment: My teacher is forcing us to use conditionals :( (see post) I initially did take an array and sort it. Very frustrating. I know.

Comment: Yes. If you have to, use them.

Comment: Did you find any errors in my Logic? I went with just trying to find the first smallest string.  Then CP and swapping objects for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class LexicographicalOrder {
        public static void main(String args[]){

            String[] mystr = {"Jack","Fortran","Amon","Cpp","Phaser"};

            for(int i=0;i<mystr.length-1;i++){
                for(int j=i+1 ;j<mystr.length;j++){

                    if( mystr[i].compareTo(mystr[j]) > 0 ){
                       String tmp = mystr[i];
                       mystr[i]= mystr[j];
                       mystr[j]=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }

             // print array 
            for(int i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){
                System.out.println(mystr[i]);
            }

        char[] mychar = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'};

        for(int i=0;i<mychar.length;i++){
          System.out.println((int)mychar[i]); // print ascii value
        }

        }
}
```

> // output
>
> - Amon
> - Cpp
> - Fortran
> - Jack
> - Phaser

Here is a simple solution hope this helpful.

Comment: thanks so much. Like I mentioned in the comments I initially went to loop through it. But my teacher is forcing us to use conditionals. ( really sucks as i've been working with rails for 6 months :(

Comment: basically the idea is ascii value 'A' has ascii value greater than 'B' and '0' has ascii value 48 so can compare with zero. I have edited answer please check this out.

Comment: for swap the value mystr[i] and mystr[j], here is tmp is helping variable

Comment: the char makes sense. So basically, You loop from "first world  to the second to last word   then looop from the second (first) to the last. You then compare them using the compareTo() method. I follow you until there. Im lost at the conditional. The print statment makes sense also.

Comment: yes and I hope you understand the process if it helps you mark the answer best answer.happy programming :)

Comment: I swap to make the array sort to make it easier.

Comment: thanks for all the help. What specifically does the swap do to make it sort easier. Thanks again.

Comment: swap means exchange value assume ara[0] = 'A' and ara[1]='B' two value in the index 0 and 1 what if I want to exchange value like - ara[0]='B' and ara[1]='A' then we need a helping variable this whole process is called swapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a logic that leads to combinatorial explosion, i.e, for every new string you add, you have to add a lot of conditions. A better approach would be as follows:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

strings.add(first);
strings.add(second);
strings.add(third);
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    int tIndex = i;
    for (int j = i; j < strings.size(); j++) {
        if(strings.get(j).compareTo(strings.get(tIndex))<0){
            tIndex = j;
        }

    }
    String tString = strings.get(i);
    strings.set(i, strings.get(tIndex));
    strings.set(tIndex, tString);

}
```